# Unit Test : Should I use verify(eq()) instead of ArgumentCaptor for checking object passing to repository?

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, junit, mockito

I have been using `ArgumentCaptor` in order to check the object passing to the save method of a respository as shown below:

```
@Captor
private ArgumentCaptor<Product> productCaptor;

@Test
void create() {

    //code omitted

    Product product = new Product();
    product.setId(101L);
    product.setName("Laptop");

    CommandResponse result = productService.create(request);
    verify(productRepository).save(productCaptor.capture());
    Product capturedProduct = productCaptor.getValue();


    verify(productRepository).save(eq(product));

    assertEquals(capturedProduct.getId(), result.id());
    assertEquals("Laptop", capturedProduct.getName());
    // ...
}
```

However, I have just sees the an example that not only checks if the save method is called, also the object passing to it (I think so):

```
verify(productRepository).save(eq(product));
```

So, if this statement check both `productRepository.save()` method is called and the object passing to this `save()` method is equal to `product`, then is it better than using a ArgumentCaptor?

Answer (score 1):

The `ArgumentCaptor` and `ArgumentMatchers` are different tools that can be use for the same purpose: to test the arguments that were being passed to the mocked object.
In other words, you should use either one or the other.  For example:

```
CommandResponse result = productService.create(request);
verify(productRepository).save(productCaptor.capture());

Product capturedProduct = productCaptor.getValue();
assertEquals(capturedProduct.getId(), result.id());
assertEquals("Laptop", capturedProduct.getName()) 
// or other asserts you might want to perform here
```

or, you can use the argumentMatcher:

```
verify(productRepository).save(ArgumentMatchers.argThat(
    product -> product.getId() == result.id()
        && "Laptop".equals(product.getName())
));
```

`ArgumentCaptpor` allows more flexibility when it comes to the asserts, and allows you to specify more specific messages if the test fails.

On the rather hand, `ArgumentMatcher` is much quicker to write and might be a good option for very simple asserts.

Comment: Thanks, but I am asking the difference between `ArgumentCaptor` and `verify(productRepository).save(eq(product));` ? Could you please re-read my explanations to be clarified about the real problem? Thanks.

Comment: yes, look: this solution `verify(productRepository).save(eq(product))` is using a argument Matcher. this `eq` stands for `ArgumentMatchers.eq(...)`. In my example, I'm just using a different matcher, the `argThat` one. I wrote some pros and cons for each, but very briefly, take a look.

Comment: I am wondering when we use it like that, does it mean to verifying the object passed to the save method is equal to the product as we compare using ArgumentCaptor? I mean, can we use eq(product) part as ArgumentCaptor? Or it has a different purpose?